# WordPress fetching all posts of a custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress

When I'm fetching all posts for a custom post type with the `get_posts()` function I always get a memory size limit has been reached even if their are only 300 posts I want to get from the database.

Increasing the memory is not an option and enabling pagination neither.

What can cause this and how can I solve this. Because from each of these posts I will later also have to fetch the meta data and split it up in 2 arrays/objects and a lot more stuff. It needs to be able to handle 5000+ posts/records per page request.

Any tips, ideas, suggestions, something else?

First try:

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'    => 300,
    'offset'            => 0,
    'category'          => '',
    'category_name'     => '',
    'orderby'           => 'title',
    'order'             => 'ASC',
    'post_type'         => 'partners',
    'post_status'       => 'publish',
    'suppress_filters'  => true,
    /*'meta_key'        => 'partner-submission-status',
    'meta_value'        => 'goedgekeurd',*/
);

$posts = get_posts($args);
var_dump(count($posts));
```

Second try:

```
$query = $wpdb->get_results("
    SELECT p.ID, p.post_title
    FROM wp_posts as p
    INNER JOIN wp_postmeta as m
    on p.ID = m.post_id
    WHERE p.post_type = 'partners' AND
    p.post_status = 'publish'
");

var_dump(count($query));die;
```

But both of them don't even get to the `var_dump`

Comment: I tried to work with the get_posts() function and with a raw query but both go over the memory size limit. I will add some code in my original post.

Comment: Have you tried increasing the WP_MEMORY_LIMIT from wp-config file ?

Comment: The problem seems to because I have 76 custom fields (meta data) the default query take is as 50000+ records to fetch and the system crashes on that. So I need to find a way to map these meta data to a separate database table so that it has one row for each partner in that post type so that it only gets on record per partner (raw query) and do everything on that. Any suggestions for that?

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php query_posts( 'post_type=your_post_type&posts_per_page=10' ); 
if (have_posts()) :  while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

...........

<?php  endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```